# APIs and front-end development

Tags: javascript, api, security, design-patterns, architecture

We are currently implementing a web application using APIs and front-end JS libraries. One concern that is currently arising from a security point of view:

is it an issue exposing these API calls in front-end code?
Since this will be a public website, an example of an API call would be getting all available products. Is it possible for the webpage to display all available products with API call (without user having to sign in), but not allow others to make this call outside of the website (for eg using a tool like fiddler)?

I guess I am looking for either an architectural pattern and/or best practices for using APIs in the front-end of publicly accessible websites.

Any guidance/links very much appreciated

Comment: You can't control what happens at the other end of an HTTP request. You have to design the application with that reality in mind.

Comment: This is a very broad question, but the closest you'll get to an answer is: the API **must** provide all security, you cannot trust the client.

Comment: *Any guidance/links* - You can't ask for links; requests to find or recommend off site resources are off topic.

Comment: Whatever security token is used by the client to authenticate requests to the site should also be used to authenticate requests to the API.  The API is no different from the rest of the site, it simply responds with JSON instead of HTML.

Comment: @David - most information will be available to anonymous users, so will not need authentication for most

Comment: Thanks for the comments. They do give some pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The api itself can limit where http requests are coming in from using various methods. Depending on the language/platform you are using you have complete control over who/what can actually perform http requests to your API.

Most people would just use CORS as an extremely basic solution. CORS will prevent unauthorized HTTP requests from coming in if they are not white listed by the API itself.

Comment: Using aspnet web api 2.
We do have Cors enabled currently.

Comment: If Cors are extremely basic, any suggestions for a more advanced solution to prevent these api's from being called from other sources/domains?

Comment: I'll mark this as an answer because it does answer the question precisely, might not solve my problem personally